# How to operate a series of different functions one by one?

Tags: java, function, series

I know in .net, I can do something like this in a task,

```
task.ContinueWith((v) =>
        {
            Operation1();
        })

            .ContinueWith((V) =>
            {
                Operation2();
            },  

            Cancel.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None, Scheduler);
        return task;
```

Or use the Aysnc/Await features to do the Operations one by one.

How can I do this in Java?

I have read the materials for AsyncTask, but the after the operation done in doInBackground, the method in onPostExecute(Result) are still be called synchronously.

So my question is How to operate a  series of different function one by one?

Comment: Could you please describe in English what the code you are looking for is supposed to do?

Comment: If you are looking for lambda functions then java do not have it yet. Java 8 with lambda will be released later in this year.

Comment: He wants to know how to chain multiple asynchronous tasks such that they execute in serial (but still asynchronously w.r.t. the caller and each other).  His C# example uses the .NET Task's `ContinueWith` method to invoke each subsequent task as a continuation upon completion (or failure) of the antecedent task.  I do this in Java using my own implementation of .NET's `Task` API, so I unfortunately can't offer a solution based on Java's core APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable with Rx, you could use [RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/).  It's not pretty, but it works:

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

final ConnectableObservable<?> result = Observable.concat(
    Observable.defer(
        new Func0<Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call() {
                return Observable.from(
                    executor.submit(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() { task(1); }
                        }
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    ),
    Observable.defer(
        new Func0<Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call() {
                return Observable.from(
                    executor.submit(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() { task(2); }
                        }
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    )
).replay();

result.connect();
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but I don't know the RxJava APIs very well, as I use my own implementation of Rx for Java.

The gist is:

1. The `concat()` operator joins multiple observable sequences in serial.  In this case, each sequence is just a single element: the result of a task.
2. The `defer()` operator prevents each task from being scheduled until someone subscribes.  In this case, that happens when the preceding task/sequence terminates.
3. The `from()` operator transforms a `Future<?>` into an `Observable<?>`.
4. The `replay()` operator creates a connectable observable, ensuring that the sequence of tasks only executes once, even if there are multiple subscribers.  The result will be captured so late subscribers will still receive it.
5. Calling `connect()` kicks off the sequence of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `onPostExecute(result)`, which seems awkward compared to C#. You may opt to be an early adapter of Java 8 with lambdas, so you could implement the same syntax:

```
.ContinueWith(v -> operation1())
```